# Animate box expansion in the center of the screen (React Native Animated)

Tags: ios, animation, react-native

Its my first time animating with react native's animated library. Is it possible to animate in the center of the screen? If so, how can I do that?

This is my code below:
I basically had a 60x60 box on the top left corner of my screen to go down 1/2 the screen and over 1/2 the width. I want it to expand horizontally about 150 px across. The problem is that the box is not expanding in the center of the screen

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Animated,
    Dimensions,
    Easing
} from 'react-native';

const {width,height} = Dimensions.get('window')
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()

        this.state = {
            width: new Animated.Value(60),//Animated.Value/ValueXY used to hook up animation attributes, also for single values
            height: new Animated.Value(60),
            animateXY : new Animated.ValueXY({x:0,y:0})//for vectors
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        //called when an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM
        Animated.sequence([
            //function where we add the ending results
            Animated.timing(
                this.state.animateXY,
                {
                toValue: {x:0, y:height/2},
                duration: 2000
            }),
            Animated.timing(
                this.state.animateXY,
                {
                    toValue: {x:width/2, y:height/2},
                    duration: 2000,
                }),
            Animated.timing(
                this.state.width,
                {
                    toValue: 150,
                    duration: 3000
                }),

        ]).start()

    }
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Animated.View
                style={
                    {
                        width: this.state.width,
                        height:this.state.height,
                        backgroundColor:"teal",
                        position:'absolute',
                        top: this.state.animateXY.y,
                        left: this.state.animateXY.x,

                    }
                }
            />
        </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Any advice will do! thank you!
Jemma

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the height. Maybe in your case you can use the width only since it’s a square